# QGIS Error Loading Shapefile with Database Manager

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatialite

I am a new QGIS user and have downloaded version 2.18.2 onto my PC (Windows 10). I'm trying to import a shapefile (using Database Manager) into a spatialite database that I created.

However, I keep getting the following error:

> Error 8 loading of the layer "layer name" failed

Can anyone help me understand what the problem might be? I can add the shapefile to QGIS desktop as a layer without any trouble.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. Can you share the Shapefile? If not, provide at least information about its fields.

Comment: Check whether your database contains a table (layer) with the same name, if there is something, delete the table and try again,